# Cypress: How to visit a url of a different origin?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, chromium, cypress

I'm new to cypress and have ran into an issue. I have my base URL set to the domain I want to test, the issue is when I want to test the ability to login on my base url site I need to verify the user on another site, once I click apply on site number 2 the page on my base url reloads and I would then be able to test the rest of the site.

When I try to visit site 2 from my test I get an error

> cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a URL that is of
>   a different origin.
>
> The new URL is considered a different origin because the following
>   parts of the URL are different:
>
> > superdomain
>
> You may only cy.visit() same-origin URLs within a single test.

I read this https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false I've tried setting `"chromeWebSecurity": false` in cypress.json but I still get the same issue (I'm running in chrome)

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is it SSO? If so, this ongoing thread might be of interest to you: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1342

Answer (score 9):

As a temporary but solid work around, I was able to find this script in one of the Cypress Git issue threads (I don't remember where I found it so I can't link back to it)

Add the below to your cypress commands file

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
        return win.open(url, '_self'); 
      });
});
```

and in your tests you can call

```js
cy.forceVisit("www.google.com")
```

Comment: calcazar thanks for your answer. I did work for me but cypress fails the test after routing to the new url, throwing Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load. Is there a way to ignore this error so the test can pass correctly?

Comment: Can you give me a snippet of your test and where it says it's failing?

Comment: Good effort, but no, that doesn't work. It goes to another URL indeed, but then cypress fails on the next test while “waiting for new page to load”.

Comment: Do you have a repo with the code that I can take a look at? Myself and others are using the above method with some level of success. My next question would be to double check your cypress version to make sure you're not too behind the version train!

Comment: Hi @calcazar. Have you tried running this in Firefox? I could not make it work. Cypress just keeps waiting for the page to load, even if the contents of the page have already appeared in the Test Runner.

Answer (score 5):

From version 9.6.0 of cypress, you can use `cy.origin`.

If you want to use it, you must first set the "experimentalSessionAndOrigin" option to true.

```json
{
  "experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true
}
```

And here's how to use it.

```js
cy.origin('www.example.com', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
})
```

`cy.origin` change the baseurl, so you can link to another external link via `cy.visit('/')`.

Answer (score 3):

You can stub the redirect from login site to base site, and assert the URL that was called.

Based on [Cypress tips and tricks](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowlocationreplace) here is a custom command to do the stubbing.

The login page may be using one of several methods to redirect, so besides the `replace(<new-url>)` stub given in the tip I've added `href = <new-url>` and `assign(<new-url>)`.

**Stubbing command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('stubRedirect', () => {
  cy.once('window:before:load', (win) => {
    win.__location = {                           // set up the stub
      replace: cy.stub().as('replace'),
      assign: cy.stub().as('assign'),
      href: null,
    } 
    cy.stub(win.__location, 'href').set(cy.stub().as('href'))
  })

  cy.intercept('GET', '*.html', (req) => {   // catch the page as it loads
    req.continue(res => {
      res.body = res.body
      .replaceAll('window.location.replace', 'window.__location.replace')
      .replaceAll('window.location.assign', 'window.__location.assign')
      .replaceAll('window.location.href', 'window.__location.href')
    })
  }).as('index')
})
```

**Test**

```js
it('checks that login page redirects to baseUrl', () => {

  cy.stubRedirect()
  cy.visit(<url-for-verifying-user>)   
  cy.wait('@index')                           // waiting for the window load

  cy.('button').contains('Apply').click()     // trigger the redirect 

  const alias = '@replace'  // or '@assign' or '@href'
                            // depending on the method used to redirect
                            // if you don't know which, try each one
  cy.get(alias)
    .should('have.been.calledOnceWith', <base-url-expected-in-redirect>)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

But, *maybe* it will be possible soon. See Cypress ticket [#944](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-853129902).

Meanwhile you can refer to my [lighthearted comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-866061363) in the same thread where I describe how I cope with the issue while Cypress devs are working on multi-domain support:

> For everyone following this, I feel your pain! [#944 (comment)](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-853129902) really gives hope, so while we're patiently waiting, here's a workaround that I'm using to write multi-domain e2e cypress tests today. Yes, it is horrible, but I hope you will forgive me my sins. Here are the four easy steps:
>
> 1. Given that you can only have one `cy.visit()` per `it`, write multiple `it`s.
> 2. Yes, your tests now depend on each other. Add [`cypress-fail-fast`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-fast) to make sure you don't even attempt to run other tests if something failed (your whole `describe` is a single test now, and it makes sense in this sick alternate reality).
> 3. It is very likely that you will need to pass data between your `it`s. Remember, we're already on this crazy “wrong” path, so nothing can stop us naughty people. Just use `cy.writeFile()` to save your state (whatever you might need), and use `cy.readFile()` to restore it at the beginning of your next `it`.
> 4. Sue me.
>
> All I care about at this point is that my system has tests. If cypress adds proper support for multiple domains, fantastic! I'll refactor my tests then. Until that happens, I'd have to live with horrible non-retriable tests. Better than not having proper e2e tests, right? Right?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the window.location.href manually which triggers a page load, this works for me:

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:8000';
cy.visit(url);

// second "visit"
cy.window().then(win => win.location.href = url);
```

You will also need to add `"chromeWebSecurity": false` to your cypress.json configuration.

Note: setting the window to navigate won't tell cypress to wait for the page load, you need to wait for the page to load yourself, or use timeout on get.

Comment: Error occurs - ***Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page***

Comment: Add config `"chromeWebSecurity": false` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @Paolo - I already had this in my config so did not know it was also required. I've updated my answer.