# URL is not openning in cypress, its open when i tried to open in chrome browser

Tags: cypress

I have written the below code in my test file but it will not open the URL in the cypress test runner.

```
describe("Failing tests", function () {
  it("Verify user can access home page", () => {
    cy.visit('https://npr--e2e.sandbox.my.site.com/contact/s/');
    cy.get('contentCaption.contentCaption').should("be.visible");
  });
});
```

This URL is open when I try to open it manually in normal browser.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053892/cypress-how-to-visit-a-url-of-a-different-origin

Comment: @JohanNordlinder i have configured chromeWebSecurity: false in cypress.config.js file and i have also tried ForceVisit command but it still not working